# How do I deal with an object sent into AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I have a function that recieves an object from Java controller. My AngularJS variable is simple:

```
var self = this;
self.item = {};
```

And my function where I get the object:

```
  function getItem() {
        MyService.getItem(REST_SERVICE_URI)
            .then(
                function (d) {
                    self.item = d;                        
                },
                function (errResponse) {
                    console.error('Error while getting item');
                }
            );
   }
```

Object that's received has rather complicated structure. It has id, name and list of child objects, who have also id and name fields. How do I get into this object's fields and list in the AngularJS controller? I tried loop though list using fucntion below to even count duplicate values but it didn't work. I tried even to include one more loop into it with outputing result in console, no effect. It only returns zeros.

```
       var i = "SOME TEST NAME VALUE TO CHECK";

       function getCount(i) {        
            var iCount = iCount || 0;        
            for (var el in self.item) {
                console.log("let me see what are you: " + el);
                if (el == i) {
                    iCount++;
                }
            }        
            return iCount;
        }
```

The object I recieve is ok, I can see it content in Chrome using F12 - Network - Response or Preview.

added later:
On my page I test it like this

```
<tr class="my_item" ng-repeat="p in ctrl.item.children">
 <span>getCount {{p.name}}: {{ctrl.getCount(p.name)}}</span>
</tr>
```

It displays p.name in the span btw. Java object structure is

```
public class Item {    
    private int id;    
    private String name;
    List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Child class is simple

```
public class Child {    
        private int id;    
        private String name;        
    }
```

Comment: post your content in qstn too.. atleast structure

Comment: post your call also to getCount()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, the content is complex and has **recursive** `properties inside child content`.

So you need to iterate on content `recursively`, inside one `forEach loop`.

*See this example working **Demo**:*

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('ExampleController', function() {
var vm = this;
  vm.count = 0;
  vm.searchTxt = "";
  vm.getCount = function() {
    vm.count = 0; //clear count before search
    recursive(vm.content);
  }


  function recursive(dataArray) { //recursive function
    dataArray.forEach(function(data) {
      if (vm.searchTxt == data.name) { //match name property
        vm.count = vm.count + 1;
      }
      if (data.child.length > 0) {
        recursive(data.child); // call recursive function
      }
    });
  }

  vm.content = [{ //example content
    id: 1,
    name: 'one',
    child: [{
      id: 1.1,
      name: 'new one',
      child: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'one',
        child: []
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'two',
    child: [{
      id: 1.1,
      name: 'new two',
      child: []
    }]
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.2/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
  <input ng-model="vm.searchTxt" placeholder="ender search.." />
  <br>
  <button ng-click="vm.getCount()">Search</button>
  <br>
  <span>Match 'Name' count : {{vm.count}}</span>
</div>
```